# ¿Cómo mostrar una foto o imagen de la carpeta Storage a la vista?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, storage

Tengo la siguiente duda y problema, estoy intentando que mi imagen se muestre en una vista de blade o HTML, ya la tengo almacenada la ruta en mi base de datos y la imagen en la carpeta Storage, cuando intento poner la ruta no se visualiza;

Vista:

```
         <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class=" card card-body text-justify col-lg-8 mx-auto">
              <font size=5 style="color:#D80606;">FOTO DE PERFIL:</font> <br><br>
              @foreach($perfil as $p)
              @if($p->file == null)
              <img src="{{ asset('images/administration/users/avatar-2.jpg') }}" alt="" width="160px" class="avatar-md mx-auto rounded-circle">
              @else
              <!-- <img src="{{asset('storage/app/'.$p->file)}}" alt="{{$p->name}}" width="160px"  class="mx-auto rounded-circle"> -->
              <!-- <img width=30px src="{{ Storage::url($p->file)}}"> -->
              <img width=30px src="{{$p->file}}">
              @endif
              <br>
              <a href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#perfil{{$p->id}}" class="btn-lg" type="button">Subir imagen</a>
              <div class="modal fade" id="perfil{{$p->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#006400; color:white">
                              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Nueva foto de perfil</h5>
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                              </button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                              <form action="{{ route('perfil_updated',$p->id) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                @csrf @method('PATCH')
                                <input type="hidden" name="ciudadano" value="{{Auth::user()->name}}">
                                <label for="">Seleccione foto:</label>
                                <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*"><br><br>
                                <center>{!! $errors->first('file', '<small class="card text-center card-personalizada" style="background-color:#DC143C; color:white"><font SIZE=3>:message</font></small><br>')!!}</center>
                                <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-light" style="background-color:#F7139B; color:white">Guardar cambios</button></center>
                              </form>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              @endforeach
            </div>
          </div>
```

Controlador:

```
                  public function perfil(){
  $perfil = DB::table('users')
  ->select('users.*')
  ->where('users.name','=',auth()->user()->name)
  ->where('users.puesto','=',null)
  ->get();
  // dd($perfil);
  return view('administration.perfil_ciudadano',[
    'perfil' => $perfil,
  ]);
}

public function pefil_updated(Request $request,$id){
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'file' => 'required|image|max:2048',
  ]);
  // dd($request);
  if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->route('perfil')
    ->withErrors($validator)
    ->withInput()
    ->with('ImagenNoModificada','Foto no Cambiada');
  }

  $name = $request->ciudadano;
  // dd($request->file);
  if(!empty($request->file)){
  $path = $request->file('file')->storeAs('Fotos_Ciudadanas/Fotografias','ciudadano'.'_'.$name.'.'.$request->file('file')->extension());
  $request->file = $path;

  $perfil_updated = User::where('id','=',$id)->first();
  $perfil_updated->file = $path;
  $perfil_updated->save();
}else{
  return back()->with('ImagenNoModificada','Foto No Cambiada');
}
  return back()->with('ImagenModificada','Foto Cambiada');
}
```

ya le inserte el comando de "php artisan storage:link" y me dice que ya existe y aun no logro que me lo muestre.

mostrare una pequeña evidencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya busque  en algunas paginas para ver si encontraba la respuesta pero aun no lo encuentro, algunas idea de lo que me esta pasando, o como mostrar mi imagen???

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás intentando acceder a una ruta que se halla fuera del `root` de tu web, prueba a poner las fotos en una carpeta dentro de `public` a ver si así funciona; o bien, crea un enlace simbólico...

Comment: seria algo haci $path = $request->file('file')->storeAs('public/Fotos_Ciudadanas/Fotografias','ciudadano'.'_'.$name.'.'.$request->file('file')->extension()); así o como por que no te entendí muy bien ???

Comment: No puedes acceder a ninguna carpeta que no esté en el ámbito de tu `root`, así que, o bien pones la carpeta con las imágenes dentro de tu carpeta `root`: `public`, o bien creas un enlace simbólico dentro de tu `root` que apunte a la carpeta de las imágenes que está fuera de él...

Comment: haya entiendo :)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: ya vi la documentación y ya le había insertado ese comando pero aun así no :(

Comment: Puede que no tengas permisos del servidor. Prueba copiando la carpeta con las imágenes dentro del `root` y al menos compruebas que funciona...

Comment: tendré que modificar el código de mi controlador de la función, por que realmente me estoy enredando yo mismo

Comment: Acabo de fijarme que en la imagen tienes una carpeta `storage`, imagino que será el enlace simbólico, pero tendrás que probar haciendo el enlace a la ruta completa: `storage/Fotos_Ciudadanas/Fotografias`, si aún no te deja acceder a ella...

Comment: ya descubrí mi problema, me bloqueaba mi imagen  por que tenia mal configurada mi  storage:link

Comment: Bueno, era el enlace simbólico, en definitiva... Me alegro de que lo hayas podido resolver.